# Customising Plone 3 sharing tab

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

Where do the titles "Can add", "Can edit", "Can view" and "Can review" come from in the plone 3 sharing tag?

What is the difference between "Can view" and "Can review"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can view" refers to the View permission which essentially controls who can view a given piece of content.

"Can review" refers to a Reviewer role which states who will be able "Review" content in the context of the publishing workflow.

These local roles are defined in plone/app/workflow/localroles.py

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, sharing tab roles in Plone 4 will be much easier to customize using GenericSetup. A custom sharing.xml step will look something like:

```
<sharing xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n" i18n:domain="plone">
    <role
        id="CopyEditor"
        title="Can edit copy"
        permission="Manage portal"
        i18n:attributes="title"
        />
</sharing>
```

Comment: Your example seems to be missing, Eric.